# AWS Tutorials: GraphQL build fails on missing symbols and too many arguments

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm trying to work through the [AWS tutorial on Android/GraphQL](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-android-app-amplify/module-four/?e=gs2020&p=build-a-react-app-three) and failing miserably. My build is failing on an autogenerated piece of code from the following command

```
amplify codegen models
```

The schema used as the source is...

```
type NoteData
@model
@auth (rules: [ { allow: owner } ]) {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    description: String
    image: String
}
```

...and the failing part of the generated code is...

```
/** This is an auto generated class representing the NoteData type in your schema. */
@SuppressWarnings("all")
@ModelConfig(pluralName = "NoteData", authRules = {
  @AuthRule(allow = AuthStrategy.OWNER, ownerField = "owner", identityClaim = "cognito:username", **provider** = "userPools", operations = { ModelOperation.CREATE, ModelOperation.UPDATE, ModelOperation.DELETE, ModelOperation.READ })
})
public final class NoteData implements Model {
  public static final QueryField ID = field("NoteData", "id");
  public static final QueryField NAME = field("NoteData", "name");
  public static final QueryField DESCRIPTION = field("NoteData", "description");
  public static final QueryField IMAGE = field("NoteData", "image");
  private final @ModelField(targetType="ID", isRequired = true) String id;
  private final @ModelField(targetType="String", isRequired = true) String name;
  private final @ModelField(targetType="String") String description;
  private final @ModelField(targetType="String") String image;
  private @ModelField(targetType="AWSDateTime", **isReadOnly** = true) Temporal.DateTime createdAt;
  private @ModelField(targetType="AWSDateTime", **isReadOnly** = true) Temporal.DateTime updatedAt;
  public String getId() {
      return id;
  }
```

My build errors are...

```
C:\Users\yawbe\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidGettingStarted\app\src\main\java\com\amplifyframework\datastore\generated\model\NoteData.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
  @AuthRule(allow = AuthStrategy.OWNER, ownerField = "owner", identityClaim = "cognito:username", provider = "userPools", operations = { ModelOperation.CREATE, ModelOperation.UPDATE, ModelOperation.DELETE, ModelOperation.READ })
                                                                                                  ^
  symbol:   method provider()
  location: @interface AuthRule
C:\Users\yawbe\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidGettingStarted\app\src\main\java\com\amplifyframework\datastore\generated\model\NoteData.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
  private @ModelField(targetType="AWSDateTime", isReadOnly = true) Temporal.DateTime createdAt;
                                                ^
  symbol:   method isReadOnly()
  location: @interface ModelField
C:\Users\yawbe\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidGettingStarted\app\src\main\java\com\amplifyframework\datastore\generated\model\NoteData.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
  private @ModelField(targetType="AWSDateTime", isReadOnly = true) Temporal.DateTime updatedAt;
                                                ^
  symbol:   method isReadOnly()
  location: @interface ModelField
C:\Users\yawbe\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidGettingStarted\app\src\main\java\com\amplifyframework\datastore\generated\model\NoteData.java:28: error: method field in class QueryField cannot be applied to given types;
  public static final QueryField ID = field("NoteData", "id");
                                      ^
  required: String
  found: String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
C:\Users\yawbe\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidGettingStarted\app\src\main\java\com\amplifyframework\datastore\generated\model\NoteData.java:29: error: method field in class QueryField cannot be applied to given types;
  public static final QueryField NAME = field("NoteData", "name");
                                        ^
  required: String
  found: String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
C:\Users\yawbe\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidGettingStarted\app\src\main\java\com\amplifyframework\datastore\generated\model\NoteData.java:30: error: method field in class QueryField cannot be applied to given types;
  public static final QueryField DESCRIPTION = field("NoteData", "description");
                                               ^
  required: String
  found: String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
C:\Users\yawbe\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidGettingStarted\app\src\main\java\com\amplifyframework\datastore\generated\model\NoteData.java:31: error: method field in class QueryField cannot be applied to given types;
  public static final QueryField IMAGE = field("NoteData", "image");
                                         ^
  required: String
  found: String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

So that looks like two undefined symbols and four calls with the wrong number of variables. Taking the latter, the tooltip shows the following usage which does indeed request a single argument.

```
public static QueryField field(String fieldName)
```

I have no idea why the autogenerated code has two but if I remove the first argument so

```
field("NoteData", "image")
```

becomes

```
field("image")
```

will that actually fix the problem or will it just sort the build errors while creating me a whole set of new runtime problems?

Back to the two undefined symbols, they don't appear to be missing imports but an incompatibility between definitions and the generated code. The source for AuthRule doesn't define a provider field so that appears to be an obvious reason for the error but what I don't understand is why amplify is putting it there in the first place and what needs to replace it (presumably something?). Same goes for the isReadOnly, it's not defined so why is amplify trying to use it?

Hopefully someone can put me straight on this, I pretty much understand all the other code to this point but it's this amplify generated file that's giving me headaches.

Comment: I was able to fix the errors by using the latest gradle dependencies listed on the [amplify-android readme](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android#using-amplify-from-your-app)

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

If you make the following changes to the Gradle Library version, no build errors occur

```
implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-api:1.24.0'
implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-auth-cognito:1.24.0'
```

Comment: That solved my issues.  Can you tell me how to find the latest stable versions each time?